# Can there be a computational characterization of HOD?

Tags: set-theory, soft-question, ordinal-computability

This is a somewhat open-ended question, so let me motivate it a little.

One of the first results in the study of Ordinal Turing Machines includes the following computational characterization of $L$ by Koepke:

> **Theorem.** a set of ordinals is in $L$ if and only if it is
> computable by an Ordinal Turing Machine with finitely many parameters.

At the same time, $\mathsf{HOD}$ has a "definable power set" characterization: in the construction on $L$, if we replace the first-order definable power set operator with second-order definable power set, then the resulting structure is $\mathsf{HOD}$. This is proved by Myhill and Scott, and is also nicely written up in this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156940/g%c3%b6dels-constructible-universe-in-infinitary-logics-a-possible-approach-to-hod).

So a natural question is this: can there be a computational notion $C$ such that something analogous to Koepke's theorem is provable for $\mathsf{HOD}$? By this I have in mind something to the effect of "a set (of ordinals) is in $\mathsf{HOD}$ if and only if it is $C$-computable."

A somewhat trivial candidate would be just oracle-OTM computation. This uses the observation that $\mathsf{HOD}$ is always coextensive with $L[A]$ for some class of ordinals $A$, and we can just relativize Koepke's theorem to $A$. But can we do more?

Comment: [A question by Dmytro Taranovsky](https://mathoverflow.net/q/357397/48041) might be relevant. (Unfortunately, it does not receive any answer.)

Comment: At some point you gotta ask yourself what counts as a computation. If you need a 2nd-order oracle mechanism, then is it really a computation?

Answer (score 1):

If you consider recognizability instead of computability, you get as far up as an inner model for a Woodin cardinal, see "Recognizable Sets and Woodin Cardinals: Computations Beyond the Constructible Universe". Of course, this is still far below HOD in general.